# Manter conexão ativa após um pedido POST

Tags: http, lua

Estou tentando criar um script para ativar o serviço QOS de controle de banda do meu roteador, mas estou fazendo algo errado, pois não consigo manter a conexão depois de fazer um pedido POST.

```
local host = '192.168.0.1'
local headers = [[]]

local LuaSocket = require("socket")
client = LuaSocket.connect(host, 80)

headers = [[Host: 192.168.0.1
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 39

Username=admin&checkEn=0&Password=admin]]

client:send("POST /LoginCheck " .. headers)
print("First request")
while 1 do
    r, err = client:receive()
    if err then 
        break
    end
    print(r)
end

headers = [[Host: 192.168.0.1
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: pt-BR,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: http://192.168.0.1/index.asp
Cookie: language=pt; admin:language=pt
Connection: keep-alive]]

client:send("GET /goform/trafficForm?GO=net_tc.asp&tc_enable=1&up_Band=12800&down_Band=12800&cur_number=2&tc_list_1=80,100,100,1,50,2000,1,1&tc_list_2=80,101,150,1,1,50,1,1 HTTP/1.0" .. headers)
print("Second request")
while 1 do
    r, err = client:receive()
    if err then 
        break
    end
    print(r)
end

client:close()
```

Ao executar, tenho isso

```
First request
HTTP/1.0 302 Redirect
Server: GoAhead-Webs
Date: Wed Aug 03 05:09:46 2016
Set-Cookie: admin:language=pt; path=/
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Type: text/html
Location: index.asp

Second request
```

Pelo navegador, tenho essa resposta do POST no /LoginCheck

```
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Wed Aug 03 05:13:15 2016
Location: index.asp
Pragma: no-cache
Server: GoAhead-Webs
Set-Cookie: admin:language=pt; path=/
```

Pelo que vi, ele faz o login, mas não sei como manter a conexão para conseguir fazer o pedido GET que ativaria o controle de banda.

OBS: Para conseguir acesso á qualquer página do roteador, preciso fazer o login na página **192.168.0.1/login.asp**, que faz um pedido POST para **192.168.0.1/LoginCheck**, e se for efetuado com sucesso, redireciona para **192.167.0.1/index.asp** e então pode se acessar as outras páginas do mesmo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para salvar os dados, é necessário subir uma sessão, para que o servidor salve os dados na sessão do usuário, o cabeçalho enviado para o servidor deve conter os dados da sessão.

```
Cookie: csrftoken=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Isso faz com que o servidor salve os dados da sessão de usuário até fechar o navegador e trocar de sessão.

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8081
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:48.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/48.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: pt-BR
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
DNT: 1
Cookie: csrftoken=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Connection: keep-alive
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
```

Esse cabeçalho é da solicitação do navegador *Firefox*, a propriedade `Cookie` presente no cabeçalho, é responsável por salvar os dados de sessão do usuário, tendo a variável `csrftoken` que possui o `id` de sessão do usuário.

Em alguns casos o `csrftoken`, não é o único valor para a sessão, tendo também o `sessionid` com o mesmo formato.